# JMeter - Load XML files from a folder and use in HTTP request body

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter, is it possible to load XML files from a directory and use it in the body of HTTP request? I have few thousand XML files that need to be used for load testing, and the data is not available in CSV format as the XML was generated by another system.

So, is there any plugin available in JMeter, which takes a directory of XML files and make the HTTP request with the content of XML file as the body. Looking for a solution that will also work when using with multiple users (threads).

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin which you can use for listing the files in the folder into a JMeter Variable
2. You can use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function in order to fetch XML file contents from the file path.